# how get value feild[ID] stdClass Object in php code

Tags: php, stdclass

how get value `feild[id]` in php code

```
stdClass Object ( [List_inserted] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 145001 [value] => 40 ) ) [Sucssess] => 1 [ErrorMassage] => OK )
```

Comment: What efforts did you give? Can you show us your efforts which doesn't work? Because its **$obj->List_inserted[0]->ID**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give us a name of `stdClass` so I'm assuming it's $stdClass.

`$stdClass->List_inserted[0]->ID`

Let's break it down;

`stdClass Object ( [List_inserted] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 145001 [value] => 40 ) ) [Sucssess] => 1 [ErrorMassage] => OK )`

We access objects with a `->` and we access arrays with `[]`
The first part tells us it's an object, so it's;

`$stdClass->List_inserted`

List_inserted is an array thanks to the `=> Array`. We can access this with [0].

`$stdClass->List_inserted[0]`

Well, List_inserted[0] is an object, thanks too `[0] => stdClass Object`; and you wanted to access the ID? So we need another `->`

`$stdClass->List_inserted[0]->ID`